# Verify if PDA exists in program using Anchor

Tags: pda

I need specifically to verify if a PDA exist inside a program without passing it as an account in the instruction. The solution I'm looking for is something like this. Thank you!

```
    let (pubkey_pda,__bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()], ctx.program_id);

    if pubkey_pda.exist() {
        /// do something
    } else {
        /// create pda
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can’t.
Solana accounts has to be passed in to read any of the data.