# Get PDAs within an anchor function

Tags: pda, anchor-lang

I know through client side I can do this to get all the PDAs for a account type.

```
let program = anchor.workspace.MyApp as Program<MyApp>
let items = await program.account.items.all();
```

But what I like to do is to call this within an Anchor function while processing some data.

```
pub fn add_item(ctx: Context<AddItem>) -> Result<()> {
   let item: &mut Account<Item> = &mut ctx.accounts.item;


   ///Do some processing on item.. 


   /// Then call all PDAs of type here. (Like get all PDAs owned by program here)


   /// Send some funds to those PDAs addresses. 


}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verify if PDA exists in program using Anchor](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9546/verify-if-pda-exists-in-program-using-anchor)